# Hexadecimal, octal, binary, oh my!

Tags: code-golf, base-conversion

This is a code golf puzzle: shortest byte count wins. The program should do the following ([standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) obviously forbidden):

1. Input a hexadecimal number
2. Convert to octal
3. Then interpret the digits as if in decimal (765 octal -> 765 decimal)
4. Divide the number by two
5. Convert to hexadecimal

### Example:

Input: 4a3d
Output: 5809.8

```
4a3d -> 45075 -> 45075 -> 22537.5 -> 5809.8
```

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I'm not the downvoter, but personally I'd vote this as a duplicate of base-conversion challenge, since that's the same, just repeated. I'd suggest you to use our [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/72792) next time, it can help detect potential problems in the challenge.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site.  I downvoted this challenge because it is a series of tasks, with no real motivation.  I don't think the challenge is interesting.  That being said don't feel discouraged to keep writing questions.  Just because I think this challenge is bad doesn't mean I think you won't write good challenges in the future.

Comment: @WhatWizard what would you consider to be an interesting challenge?

Comment: The most recent challenge I have upvoted was [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/158222).  The main criteria I look for in a question are 1) Whether the challenge offers something new I haven't seen before 2) Whether the challenge is cohesive, that is whether its internal parts make sense with one another. 3) an arbitrary do I think it is fun criterion.  If you want to get good at writing challenges I would suggest reading [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047).  You might also look at [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14978).

Comment: I think it's nothing related to [the pointed dup](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69155/). A possible dup should do some base converting, though maybe no division

Comment: @l4m2 But the duplicate target does involve base conversion...

Comment: @user202729 the target only do one per call. Also it matters the char order while here doesn't

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic It's been about a year since I created this question. Thanks for the feedback you gave, as it really helped me in future questions to avoid this mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 30 bytes

```perl6
{(:16($_).base(8)/2).base(16)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WsPK0ExDJV5TLymxOFXDQlPfCMo0NNOs/V@cWKmQpqFukmicoq5p/R8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript,<s>56</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @ovs

-1 byte thanks to @Arnauld

```
p=parseInt,a=>(p(p(a,16)[s='toString'](8))/2)[s](16)
```

toString on an integer converts the integer to a string in that base.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqHxv8C2ILGoONUzr0Qn0dZOowAIE3UMzTSji23VS/KDS4oy89LVYzUsNDX1jYCCsRpAuf@aGkomicYpSpqa/wE)

Comment: Had no idea the .toString(_base_) thing existed. Upvote for teaching me something new!