# All you have to do is print the number 1! ...Twice

Tags: code-golf, unicode

## Your task

In your language of choice: create a program that outputs `1`

This `1` may either be a string or value equivalent to the number one.

## The shifting catch

If you take the **unicode codepoint** (or whatever codepoint encoding your languages uses if not UTF) for each character in your program, and shift each of those values by the **same non-zero amount**, then the result will be another program (potentially executable in different language) that also outputs `1`.

**Find the unicode codepoint of a character:** [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm).

**E.g;**

If your program looked like: `X?$A`, and somehow output `1`, and it also miraculously outputs `1` after shifting all of it's Unicode indices up by, say, 10; then that process of shifting looks like this:

```
original program: X?$A

letter    codepoint  shift   new-codepoint   new-letter

X            88       +10        98          b   
 ?           63                  73          I
  $          36                  46          .
   A         65                  75          K

new program: BI.K
```

**Note:** The Unicode codepoint will often be represented  in the form similar to `U+0058`. `58` is the **hexadecimal** codepoint . In **decimal**, that's `88`. The link above will list `88` under the `UTF (decimal)` encoding section. That is the number you want to increment or decrement!

## Examples of valid outputs

```
1
"1"
'1'
[1]
(1)
1.0
00000001
one
```

**Note:** If your language only supports the output of `true` as an equivalent to `1`, that is acceptable. Exit-codes are also valid outputs.

## Scoring

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **lowest bytes wins**!
- Brownie points for creativity & if the two programs are in separate languages.

Comment: What if a language uses a different encoding instead of UTF-8 (i.e. [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page), [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page), etc.)? Do we still use the unicode codepoints, or the codepoints of the used language?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen For the sake of making this challenge not impossible, you can use either.

Comment: If two distinct 1-char programs in a language output 1, wouldn't it win the challenge? (or how about a 0-char program?)

Comment: @Bubbler That's valid! As you know, creativity seems to dominate votes more than byte-count anyways.

Comment: I guess output via exit code code is not allowed? Otherwise, Java, 0 bytes: https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@DwQA

Comment: @ovs I think that's right on the border between valid and invalid. You're welcome to post it anyway.

Comment: @ovs [Outputting through exit code is a default valid option by the meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5330/52210), so it should be fine.

Comment: Can I have a shift of 0?

Comment: What if 2 languages output 1 with the empty program? Does `print(1)` win the brownie points?

Comment: Does this count as "restricted-source"?

Comment: @Lyxal A shift of 0 would not satisfy “… then the result will be **another** program …”, nor would a 0 byte answer.

Comment: @Lyxal Cheeky, but no. :)

Comment: @Graviton Could you please add that to the question body, since rules of a challenge shouldn't be specified only in the comments.

Comment: @pppery The question has now been updated to fit all the previous clarifications in the comments. No answers have been made invalid.

Comment: Is it the shift modulo? So does the shift by 2147483648 counts?

Comment: @Hauleth I would expect that to mean the shifrted program would consist entirely of Unicode noncharacters.

Comment: @pppery this is amount of possible Unicode codepoints, so it should be the same as 0 shift.

Answer (score 35):

## Java, 62 bytes

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(1);}}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z8zryS1KC0xOVXBt7q4JLEkM1mhLD8zRSE3MTNPI7ikKDMvPTo2UbM6uLK4JDVXL7@0RK8AKFiiYahpXVv7/z8A)

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 62 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
\agXeYTVXι@nfgTg\Vιib\Wι`T\a₂Fge\aZNPT₃nFlfgX`!bhg!ce\ag₂$₃.pp
```

Uses the 05AB1E encoding, with the codepoints all decreased by 13:

- `interface M{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(1);}}` has the codepoints `[105,110,116,101,114,102,97,99,101,32,77,123,115,116,97,116,105,99,32,118,111,105,100,32,109,97,105,110,40,83,116,114,105,110,103,91,93,97,41,123,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,49,41,59,125,125]`
- `` \agXeYTVXι@nfgTg\Vιib\Wι`T\a₂Fge\aZNPT₃nFlfgX`!bhg!ce\ag₂$₃.pp `` has the codepoints `[92,97,103,88,101,89,84,86,88,19,64,110,102,103,84,103,92,86,19,105,98,92,87,19,96,84,92,97,27,70,103,101,92,97,90,78,80,84,28,110,70,108,102,103,88,96,33,98,104,103,33,99,101,92,97,103,27,36,28,46,112,112]`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/JjE9IjUyJCzi3E6HvLT0kPSYsHM7M5Niws/tTAiJSXzU1OSWnhqTGOUXEPKoqTnPLSctPSJBMSkjXTEZKJwOlFcBiusVFPz/DwA)

#### Explanation:

**Java:**

```java
interface M{                   // Full program:
  static void main(String[]a){ //  Mandatory main-method:
    System.out.print(          //   Print without trailing newline:
      1);}}                    //    Print 1
```

**05AB1E:**

```python
\                  # Discard the top of the stack (no-op, since it's already empty)
                   #  STACK: []
 a                 # Check if it only consists of letters (resulting in falsey/0
                   # for an empty string "", which is used implicitly without input)
                   #  STACK: [0]
  g                # Push and push its length, which is 1
                   #  STACK: [1]
   X               # Push variable `X`, which is 1 by default
                   #  STACK: [1,1]
    e              # Push the number of permutations n!/(n-r)! with both 1s, which is 1
                   #  STACK: [1]
     Y             # Push variable `Y`, which is 2 by default
                   #  STACK: [1,2]
      T            # Push builtin 10
                   #  STACK: [1,2,10]
       V           # Pop and store it in variable `Y`
                   #  STACK: [1,2]
        X          # Push variable `X` again, which is 1 by default
                   #  STACK: [1,2,1]
         ι         # Uninterleave using the 2 and 1, resulting in ["2"]
                   #  STACK: [1,["2"]]
          @        # Check whether 1 is >= ["2"], resulting in [0]
                   #  STACK: [[0]]
           n       # Square it
                   #  STACK: [[0]]
            f      # Get a list of all prime factors (none for 0), which results in []
                   #  STACK: [[[]]]
             g     # Pop and push its length
                   #  STACK: [1]
              T    # Push builtin 10
                   #  STACK: [1,10]
               g   # Pop and push its length
                   #  STACK: [1,2]
                \  # Discard it
                   #  STACK: [1]
                 V # Pop and store it in variable `Y`
                   #  STACK: []
```

From here on out I can't really explain it anymore, since it does things I wasn't expecting:

```python
ι                  # Uninterleave (would take either one or two arguments, but since the
                   # stack is empty, it somehow remembered the 1 that was previously on
                   # the stack and results in ["1"] - 
                   # A program `ι` without input would result in an error instead..)
                   #  STACK: [["1"]]
 i                 # If-statement, which will be entered if the top is 1;
                   # since it's ["1"] instead of 1, it won't enter
                   #  STACK: []
  b\Wι`T\a₂Fge\aZNPT₃nFlfgX`!bhg!ce\ag₂$₃.pp
                   #  No-ops within the if-statement
                   # It again somehow remembers the previous ["1"] that was on the stack,
                   # which is output implicitly as result
```

Comment: Ok, nevermind, the perl one didn't take the most effort, this did.

Comment: @PkmnQ Tbh, it wasn't that much effort. :) I simply created the Java program, and then first used [this program](https://tinyurl.com/ybwxt3vm) to check all possible variations of decreasing codepoints using ASCII encoding (which weren't very useful), and then I used [this program](https://tinyurl.com/yc99vvaq) to check all possible variations of decreasing codepoints using 05AB1E's encoding, for which this -13 resulted conveniently in `["1"]`. Writing the explanation above took more effort to be completely honest. ;)

Comment: And if none of those would have worked, I could have changed the class-name `M` to something more convenient to try and make it output `1`.

Answer (score 32):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
1*1
```

(Works in Japt too.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fUMvw/38A)

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
6/6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/30zf7P9/AA)

Derived from the 05AB1E program by shifting by 5 *Unicode* codepoints.

The Japt program performs division, but don't be fooled into thinking that the 05AB1E program is performing multiplication. The `*` (square) operator acts only on the first `1`; the output is actually just an implicit print of the second `1`.

The same idea works with the 05AB1E/Japt program pairs `1-1` and `3/3` (shift 2) and `1+1` and `5/5` (shift 4).

Comment: It can indeed be done in 1 byte, but I like your approach more. :) Maybe this challenge should have been [tag:code-bowling] instead of [tag:code-golf], since that's much more impressive imo.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks. I agree it's not particularly impressive, especially since it was a complete stab in the dark - it just happened to work in the first two languages I picked! Very lucky choice :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Code bowling will quickly break with two programs of arbitrary length, each being a repetition of single built-in.

Comment: @Bubbler Good point. Creating a good code-bowling challenge is also pretty hard to begin with, since there are so many edge-cases you have to keep in mind.

Answer (score 19):

## Python 3, <s>19</s> 17 bytes

<sup>**-2 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan**</sup>

```
#]pal )!␛
exit(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Xzm2IDFHQVNRmiu1IrNEw1Dz/38A)

### Shifted +8

```
+exit(1)#␒m␣q|091
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Xzu1IrNEw1BTWSj3UENhjYGl4f//AA)

where ␛, ␒ and ␣ are literal `\x1b`, `\x12` and `\x80` bytes respectively.

Not much by the way of trickery going on here except prepending the print in the shift version with a `+` so that when we shift it the first character of the second program to the `#` character it doesn't send any characters into a negative codepoint (if we naïvely shifted `e` back to `#`, `(` would be sent to `\x-` which doesn't exist). Outputs by exit code.

Comment: If you output via exit code you save 2 bytes: [`+exit(1)#□m□q|091`.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Xzm2IDFHQVNRmiu1IrNEw1Dz/38A)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks! Avoids the error too because you exit first - nice.

Answer (score 16):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2x 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Without an input, any of these single characters will output `1`, so just pick two you like. :)

- `1` (self explanatory): [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8P9/AA)
- `X` (variable, which is 1 by default): [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/4v9/AA)
- `≠` (`!= 1` check; without input it will do `"" != 1`, resulting in truthy/1): [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UeeC//8B)
- `@` (`>=` check; without input it will do `"" >= ""`, resulting in truthy/1): [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4f9/AA)
- `Q` (`==` check; without input it will do `"" == ""`, resulting in truthy/1): [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/8P9/AA)

Answer (score 13):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2x2 bytes

```apl
*0
+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b@WAZe2IYj5P43rUd/UUOdgBXUtbQNDdQA)

`*0` computes `e^0`, and `+1` computes complex conjugate of 1. `*0` has Unicode codepoint 42 and 48, and `+1` has 43 and 49, so the two are different by exactly one.

Also works in many different flavors of APL, including... (copied from [Adám's APL bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/78410))

> [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/) Classic/Unicode/[Extended](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended)/[Prime](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-prime), [APL2](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/apl2/details), [APL+](http://apl2000.com/), [APLSE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gemesys.android.aplse), [GNU/APL](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/), [Sharp APL](http://www.sigapl.org/Archives/waterloo_archive/apl/sharp.apl/index.html), [sAPL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gemesys.android.sapl), [SAX](https://github.com/tobia/luit-sax), [NARS](http://www.nars2000.org/), [APLX](https://www.dyalog.com/aplx.htm), [A+](http://www.aplusdev.org/index.html), [dzaima/APL](https://github.com/dzaima/apl), [ngn/APL](https://gitlab.com/n9n/apl), [APL\iv](https://github.com/ktye/iv), [Watcom APL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gemesys.android.watapl), or [APL\360](http://wotho.ethz.ch/mvt4apl-2.00/).

... which makes this a polyglot of at least 19 languages!

Comment: [A whole lot more languages](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Language_developers).

Comment: That's beautiful.

Comment: Also works in Jelly

Answer (score 12):

## Unary, 84 bytes

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Outputs the character with codepoint 1 (equivalent brainfuck: `+.`). Since Unary cares only about the length of the program, a shift of any number will not change the output.

Comment: This comes very close to violating a standard loophole:[Using a language's lack of features to trivialize a challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11355/1352)

Comment: @Brian I wouldn't call "cares only about the length of the program" a lack of features: a Unary program can do anything a Brainfuck program can do (and Brainfuck is a Turing complete language), even though the Unary program is usually long enough its length has to be expressed in scientific notation.

Comment: I do appreciate that other users are making an effort to check the validity of my answer, though.

Answer (score 12):

## HTML, 8 bytes

```html
<ol><li>
```

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
!TQ#!QN#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fMSRQWTHQT/n/fwA)

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
([X*(XU*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/18jOkJLIyJU6/9/AA)

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
5he75eb7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/980I9XcNDXJ/P9/AA)

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
;nk=;kh=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/986L9vWOjvD9v9/AA)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
@spB@pmB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fobjAyaEg1@n/fwA)

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
H{xJHxuJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@jusLLo6LU6/9/AA)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

Outputs `["1"]`.

```
Q„SQ~S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/8FDLocbgwEONdcH//wMA)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
V‰†XV†ƒX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/7FDnobaIsENth5oj/v8HAA)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
X‹ˆZXˆ…Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/4lD3oY6oiEMdh1qj/v8HAA)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
]_]Š_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/9tCEQ73xsYd6D3XF//8PAA)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
a”‘ca‘Žc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/8dCUQxOTEw9NPNSX/P8/AA)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
e˜•ge•’g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/9dCMQ1PTUw9NPTQp/f9/AA)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
kž›mk›˜m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@9C8Q7Nzsw/NPjQj9/9/AA)

---

<sup>("Pffffft! Of *course* I know how 05AB1E and Jelly work! I *totally* didn't just brute-force a bunch of combinations on TIO. That would be [crazy](https://tio.run/##LYyxCsMgFEX3fMUjkyJ5QylZqkLJJziWDGKT9BXjC0b6@8ahFw5nOHC//ufPkOkoQ@L3UqszveZodSTbdytnQWBguI8PINAw3pqVkh20BU4nxwUjb8KVTGnDNfM@fXye2pdAxFfDzbj7QwRjA4Z/exYhFUkpa70A)! It would *never* work!")</sup>

Comment: So many! You deserve to be accepted as the best answer. Unfortunately, I'm not the one who made this question

Answer (score 9):

## CSS, 48 bytes

```css
body:after{content:"1"}z|ancx9`esdqzbnmsdms9!0!|
```

```css
cpez;bgufs|dpoufou;#2#~{}body:after{content:"1"}
```

Comment: The second code is not even close to valid CSS, but CSS parsers are so lax it works. Wow.

Answer (score 8):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), 4 bytes

```
1@/>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/f0EHf7v9/AA)

### Explanation

```
1    # Pushes 1
 @   # Prints top of the stack (1)
  /> # Pushes some meaningless stuff
```

## Shifted +2

```
3B1@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S03OSylITkzMKcop@P/f2MnQ4f9/AA)

### Explanation

```
3B   # Pushes some meaningless stuff
  1  # Pushes 1
   @ # Prints top of the stack (1)
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2 bytes

```
s1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v9jw/38A)

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 2 bytes, Shifted +1

```
t2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v8To/38A)

---

First Program translates to `floor(1)`
Second Program translates to `2 - 1`

Answer (score 7):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 2 x 18 bytes

```
" " " ␋ ␌
␋   ␌
" ␋
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0kBBLk5ebhAGMT6/x8A).

All codepoints decreased by 2 will result in:

```
 ␟ ␟ ␟  ␇
␈   ␇
␈ ␟ ␇
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0EOBDnZuThAGMT6/x8A)

Both programs contain unprintables. The first program contains characters with the codepoints: `[34,32,34,32,34,32,11,9,12,10,11,9,12,10,34,32,11,9]`. The second program with codepoints: `[32,30,32,30,32,30,9,7,10,8,9,7,10,8,32,30,9,7]`. In Whitespace, all characters except for spaces (codepoint 32), tabs (codepoint 9), and newlines (codepoint 10) are ignored, so both programs are actually the following:

```
SSSTN
TN
ST
```

Where `S`, `T`, and `N` are spaces, tabs, and newlines respectively.

This program will:

- `SSSTN`: Push 1
- `TNST`: Print it as integer to STDOUT

It's actually possible to create 3 x 27 bytes, 4 x 36 bytes, and even 5 x 45 bytes programs by having the codepoints apart by 2, still resulting in the same basic program above after all non-whitespace characters are ignored.

Comment: Does anyone know how to display unprintables in a stackexchange answer? IIRC I've seen it in an answer here on codegolf once before, but I have no idea what markup to use to accomplish it anymore.

Comment: We used the characters from the [Control Pictures block](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2400) in [Add a language to a polyglot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot?page=10&tab=oldest#tab-top) to represent ESC, formfeed and vertical tab.

Including a hexdump is probably the better option.

Comment: @Potato44 Thanks. Added the unicode unprintable characters to my answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

## J, <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
=0
```

Monadic `=` means self-classify. It compares each item with each other item to see if it's the same. 0 is 0. It returns 1.

## Shifted +1

```
>1
```

Unboxes 1, which does nothing, because it wasn't in a box in the first place.

### Alternate 2-byters:

`!1` (1 factorial) shifted by 2 is `#3` (amount of items in 3)

`!0` (0 factorial) shifted by 2 is `#2` (amount of items in 2) shifted by 7 is `*9` (sign of 9)

Comment: 2 bytes: `!1` → `#3`

Comment: Also `!0` → `*9`

Comment: @Adám Didn't see your comments while editing. I'll add those as alternate 2-byters.

Comment: 3 programs with `!0` -> `#2` -> `*9`

Comment: That also means `#1` and `*8`, and `#0` and `*7` are also valid pairs.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (web), 19 bytes

### Form #1

```js
`kdqs_0_:`;alert`1`
```

### Form #2 (#1 shifted by +1)

```js
alert`1`;a<bmfsua2a
```

This took me longer than what I'd like to admit, but it was a fun challenge.

Form #2 throws a `ReferenceError`, but [that seems to be allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/95061).

Answer (score 6):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 3 bytes

Outputs the character with the codepoint 1. [This is allowed by default.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18027/92069)

```
(+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fQ1vv/38A)

## Shifted +3

```
+.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fW8/w/38A)

### Explanation

The `+` character increments the current item of the tape, and `.` outputs that value as a character. All other characters are ignored.

Answer (score 6):

## Polyglot, 3 bytes

Shift of 2. Works in R, Octave, Japt, and probably others.

```matlab
1+0
3-2
```

[Try it online (Octave)](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fUNuAy1jX6P9/AA)

[Try it online (R)](https://tio.run/##K/r/31DbgMtY1@j/fwA)

[Try it online (Japt)](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/31jX6P9/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 1 [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Among many others:

```
1
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=MQ)

```
Ä
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xA)

```
l
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bA)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 4 bytes

```r
\061\043\030\077
```

(octal bytes, equivalent to: `'1' '#' CAN '?'`)

Shifted -14:

```r
\043\025\012\061
```

(octal bytes, equivalent to `'#' NAK LF '1'`)

Unshifted program consists of number 1 (which is outputted unchanged), followed by `#` (comment character) and 'comments' of CAN (ASCII code \030) and '?'.

Shifted +14 program consists of `#` (comment character) and 'comment' of NAK (ASCII code \025), followed by a new line.  On the next line is the number 1 (which is outputted unchanged).

Test at bash command-line using `echo` (or `gecho`):

```r
echo -e '\061\043\030\077' >prog1.r
echo -e '\043\025\012\061' >prog2.r
Rscript prog1.r
# [1] 1
Rscript prog2.r
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 6 bytes

```
1print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//9@woCgzr@T/fwA)

## [Commentator](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Commentator), (Shifted -17)

```
 _aX]c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PzU3NK0ksyS/6/18hPjEiNvn/fwA)

Comment: ...I'm interested in learning commentator now.

Answer (score 4):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 4 bytes

```
1a1o
```

**Explanation**

```
1a # Add 1 to the register
1o # Output once
```

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 bytes

```
2b2p
```

A shift of 1 Unicode codepoint forward from the original.

**Explanation**

```py
2    # Push 2
 b   # Convert to binary
  2  # Push 2
   p # Push isPrime(2)
# ...after which the result is output implicitly
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 [byte](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

`¬` (logical NOT) vs `‘` (increment)

**[Try `¬` online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Qmv//AQ)** or **[Try `‘` online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4z//wE)**

This works because given no input a Jelly program has a default argument of `0`.

There are \$\binom{21}{2}=210\$ different pairs of single-byte programs to choose from since there are \$21\$ single bytes on Jelly's [code-page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) which yield `1` with no input:

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 1 byte (SBCS)

```
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f8P9/AA)

Implicitly outputs 1

### Shifted +198

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////w/yWpv//AQ)

Uses the push'n'print to print 1

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, <s>27</s> 17 bytes

```
:_]bi�+�4
@echo 1
```

The `:` introduces a label of unprintables, so the line is ignored, and the second line prints `1`. Shifted by 6:

```
@echo 1
:�Fkinu&7
```

Much the same, except this time the second line is ignored.

Unfortunately I've mangled the unprintables. Sorry about that. Feel free to fix it.

Comment: Was waiting for a batch one to come around! Well done.

Answer (score 3):

## [;#+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/shp), 4 bytes

```
9n;p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K84o@P/fMs8aSAIA)

## [;#+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/shp), 4 bytes, Shift +2

```
;p=r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K84o@P/fusC26P9/AA)

---

### Explanation

`;` - increments the counter
`p` - outputs the counter as a number

`9`, `n`, `=` and `r` are not commands in [;#+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/shp) so they can be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 6 bytes

```
i1<esc><nul>h0
```

- Original: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9NQmiHD4P9/AA)
- Shifted: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P8tIhjHT8P9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## bc (?), 3 bytes

```
1+0
```

Shift 2:

```
3-2
```

Use as `echo 1+0 | bc` in bash.

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 5 bytes

```
=-1!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/99W11DR4f9/AA)

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 5 bytes, Shifted -12

```
1!%4
```

**Hexdump:**

```
00000000  31 21 25 15 34     |1!%.4|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/99QUVXU5P9/AA)

## Explanation

Because of the small size and lack of mirrors, the programs are mostly executed linearly.

#### Non-shifted Program

```
=       Reverse direction of memory pointer
 -      Sets the current memory edge to the difference of the left and right neighbors (0 - 0 = 0)
  1     Multiply current memory edge by 10 then add 1 (0 * 10 + 1 = 1)
   !    Outputs the value of current memory edge to stdout as an integer
    @   Terminate the program
```

#### Shifted Program

```
1       Multiply current memory edge by 10 then add 1 (0 * 10 + 1 = 1)
 !      Outputs the value of current memory edge to stdout as an integer
  %     Sets the current memory edge to the modulo of the left and right neighbours
        (1 % 0) causes program to exit because of division by 0
    4   Does not matter since the program as already exited
```

Answer (score 2):

## `pdfTeX -halt-on-error`, 1 byte

```
_
```

and

```
^
```

Both versions will throw an error as `_` and `^` are only allowed in math-mode. Will return a 1 as exit code (due to the error).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -p, 8 bytes + 1 byte/keypress input = 9 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes and much nicer printable programs thanks to Dom Hastings*

Each program requires input of 1 byte, or a single carriage-return keypress.
I've counted this as +1 byte, but I'm not terribly sure how valid this is...

```
$_++#^**
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXltbOU5L6///RK5/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Shifted +1:

```
%`,,$_++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/181QUdHJV5b@///JK5/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

One might (validly) argue that since the extra input/keypress is part of the byte-count, it should also be shifted along with the codepoints of the program.  Fortunately, there are inputs for which this works Ok:

```
echo 'a' | perl -pe '$_++#^**'
# 1
echo 'b' | perl -pe '%`,,$_++'
# 1
```

Comment: Nice, I did look into this, but wasn't sure about input being valid either... If it is, you can use a shift of `1` (again, lets avoid unprintables :P) for these two: https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXltbOU5L6/9/rn/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/181QUdHJV5b@/9/rn/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA

Comment: Those versions are a *big* improvement!  I'm very ashamed that I didn't find that solution, which is much nicer (especially for the printability).  Will update answer with acknowledgement, while anyway cautiously waiting to see whether there's any consensus about (non-) validity...

Comment: No problem! I'm sure there was a consensus about this a while ago, but I couldn't find the right meta post... Perl's syntax is frighteningly forgiving, `` $` `` is probably a syntax error in more utility languages than it's not! I'm enjoying this challenge...

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript, 3**

`3-2` becomes `2,1` shifted by -1.
`1+0` becomes `2,1` shifted by +1.

Which is cool because `1+0` shifted by one becomes `2,1` shifted by one becomes `3-2` all three produce 1

---

```js
let code = '1+0';
console.log (code, eval(code));
code = code.split('').map(c => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1)).join('');
console.log (code, eval(code));
code = code.split('').map(c => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1)).join('');
console.log (code, eval(code));
```

Comment: Would this work, and be the same size, for any sngle digit integers (a,b) where a=b+1?

Comment: @ouflak No, because in the case of `2,1` the expression evaluates to the second value, which has to be one. It only works with 0 and 2.

Comment: This isn't actually outputting anything though. Are you sure you don't mean a Javascript REPL rather than actual Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CJam), 1 byte

```
1
```

```
X
```

For whatever reason, CJam has `X` as a builtin for 1, and since it outputs implicitly, you can just use those two. However, I thought it'd be more interesting to find a 2-byte solution.

```
XR
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/PyLo/38A)

Offset by +38:

```
2,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/30jn/38A)

Explanations:

```
X    Push 1 to the stack
 R   Push an empty array to the stack
     (implicit) Output the stack
```

```
2    Push 2 to the stack
 ,   Pop and push range from 0 to 1 less than the popped number
     (implicit) Output the stack
```

Note that this is not only my first time golfing, but also my first time coding a program (well, programs) in CJam, so let me know how I did!

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 2 bytes

```
not(0
```

```
iPart(1
```

Both display `1`. Using one-byte [TI-BASIC tokens](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens) and their hexadecimal values. `not(` has a value of `0xB8`, `iPart(` has a value of `0xB9`, `0` has a value of `0x30`, and `1` has a value of `0x31`.

---

Alternatives (assuming fresh state on calculator):

- **2 bytes**: `not(A` and `e^(H`
- **2 bytes**: `e^(A` and `10^(C`
- **2 bytes**: `not(A` and `10^(J`
- **2 bytes**: `e^(A` and `cosh(L`
- **2 bytes**: `10^(A` and `cosh(J`
- **2 bytes**: `int(1` and `10^(A`
- **2 bytes**: `int(1` and `cosh(J`
- **2 bytes**: `abs(1` and `cosh(I`
- **2 bytes**: `iPart(1` and `cosh(B`
- **2 bytes**: `not(0` and `cosh(B`

Answer (score 1):

## [Brainetry](https://github.com/RojerGS/brainetry), 23 bytes

Golfed version (both lines end with a space):

```
# # # #  
# # # # # # #
```

We must shift the `#`s so they become spaces  for the program to work again, so the required shift is -3.

The base program from which I derived the above:

```
This Brainetry program takes 
no input and prints the codepoint 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Turing Machine Code](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 19 bytes

```
0 _ 1 r 1
1!'!2!s!2
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?b75a17f7335209d5ec8d4601b83f1d1c)

Nothing too fancy. If the code is shifted by -1, the second line transforms into the code of the first line. The first line transforms into an unexecutable bit of code. The interpreter can, and does, run just fine with unexecutable code dispersed here and there, and so it is just executing the same code either way.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl -M5.010, 13 bytes

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

```
 say 1#BELp^vGS.
```

`BEL` = ASCII 'BEL' character, octal byte \0007
`GS` = ASCII 'GS' character, octal byte \0035

Shifted +3:

```
#vd|#4&
say 1
```

Same approach as my R answer, but with slightly (+4 characters) more verbose outputting in Perl -M5.010.
Equivalent Perl 5 program-pair (using `print` instead of `say`) is `print 1#BELmofkqGS.` and, shifted +3, `#sulqw#4&LFprint 1`.

Test at bash command-line using `echo` (or `gecho`):

```
echo -e ' say 1#\0007p^v\0035.' > prog1.pl
echo -e '#vd|#4&\0012say 1' > prog2.pl
perl -M5.010 prog1.pl
# 1
perl -M5.010 prog2.pl
# 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 11 bytes

Uses a shift of `3`.

```perl
p^v,, say//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/78grkxHR6E4sVJf////f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwN9AwA)

```perl
say//#vd|22
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJfX7kspcbI6P//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwN9AwA)

### Explanation

`p^v` computes the bitwise `XOR` of `p` and `v` then calls `say//`. `//` returns `1` because the empty string exists within `$_` (which is the empty string).

In the shifted program, `say//` is called immediately and the rest of the program is commented out.

Comment: Really nice that you've managed to avoid non-printable characters.

Comment: Thanks! The `a` made it more tricky than I'd have liked, `print` would have been much easier!

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 1 byte

```
^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P@7/fwA)

Shifted by `30`:

```
|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/v@b/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) + `-d output_buffering=on`, 21 bytes

```php
<?=1;#;><*na^bkd`m'(:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7W0FrZ2s5GKy8xLik7JSFXXcPq//9/@QUlmfl5xf91UxTyS0sKSkvik0rT0lKLMvPSbfPzAA)

Shifted by `1`:

```php
=@>2<$<?=+ob_clean();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/f1sHOyEbFxt5WOz8pPjknNTFPQ9P6//9/@QUlmfl5xf91UxTyS0sKSkvik0rT0lKLMvPSbfPzAA)

Using the [same technique as my `Shifting Oritented Programming` answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158337/9365), it's possible to get all 256 shifts for 5,366 bytes:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7dhBa4MwFMDxu5/i0XVTKVGi6GHa9rr72Fk0xkbokhCVsU/vbO3cGFjE2@Ddwi/J439@Rd6IXnNzBqI52Eyod500vuczYRxHmdLZPrk7Z@sR6rqPQRS7/onbkKYp2OlxT5Oy5snxYA3nnSoydua5dFxUVFRUVFRUVFRUVFRUVFRUVFRUVNR/pzYcoFHa00In/cP3EZjhectLqCW88LzkxrI@GBA2vbUszoQCImHzJhtRV8PrZ9gk1uU3KaERyrSZ0lxmbX7aK3lB1bW6a7Oiqypuannl28DruGHqz@7679aa0N8L66n0mk/HpinpdQyC4hPo2iq6NCu@0xXfCYtXl8UL08JgPi0M5tPCYG3aOHVBWhBF823D5XzccLm27ja3778A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 7 bytes

Original code:

```
>1.@B03
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/385Qz8HJwPj/fwA)

Shifted by `-2`:

```
</,>@.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/30Zfx85Bz/D/fwA)

Comment: You don't have to have a separate character for `>`/`<` when you can turn the `1` into `<`, e.g. `1.@5#&` shifted by 11

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 1 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
æ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=91&i=&a=1)

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 1 bytes

```
1
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=1&i=&a=1)

I'm not sure what the offset is, but any two single-character programs can be shifted to each other.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) x2, 6 bytes

Uses a shift of 11.

```
1n;0c&
```

Puts 1 on the stack, outputs it as a number and stops.

```
<yF;n1
```

`<` makes the direction change and start executing code from the end of the line. Puts 1 on the stack, outputs it as a number and stops.

Comment: @JoKing you're right, that's better. Edited, thanks !

Comment: Actually, you can do one byte better by not swapping directions at all and reusing the `;` as a `1`. `1n;xE` shifted by -10 to get `'d1n;`

Answer (score 1):

## [Javastack](https://github.com/chunkybanana/javastack) , 1 byte

```
1
```

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/vyxal/vyxal), 1 byte

Vyxal pads the stack with 0s when there's no input, so the list includes but is not limited to...

- `›` - 0 incremented
- `ċ` - 0 != 1
- `≥` - 0 >= 0
- `≤` - 0 <= 0
- `=` - 0 == 0
- `¬` - !0
- `₃` - 0 % 3 == 0
- `₂` - 0 % 2 == 0
- `₅` - 0 % 5 == 0
- `L` - len(str(0))
- `⌐` - 1 - 0
- `e` - 0 ** 0
- `ż`, if I can output in a singleton list

Comment: Actually, `1` in Vyxal wouldn't be valid for this challenge, because there needs to be a shift of at least `1` in the codepoints of the two programs

Comment: @exedraj Oh true

Comment: @pxeger Any of the chars in the Vyxal list

Comment: Oh I missed that it could be a different langauge

Answer (score 1):

## [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)'s type system, 8 bytes

```typescript
type F=1
```

## [Vyxal 2](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 8 bytes

```
‹←↓u0VMA
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLigLnihpDihpN1MFZNQSIsIiIsIiJd)

Each character is offset by +16 in Vyxal 2's codepage.

The TypeScript program actually outputs `1` in Vyxal as well, but the shift must be nonzero.

The TypeScript type system program was very easy to write. I found the Vyxal program using [this code](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCJgdHlwZSBGPTFgw7jin4cxNivDuOKfh+G5hcSWIiwiIiwiIl0=), changing the offset by 1 and rerunning until I found a working program.

The first 6 characters of the Vyxal program do nothing particularly logical, but end up with `0` on the stack (which is quite common for random characters with no particular meaning). `M` tries to map over a list by a function, but with no list or function given, it just outputs an empty list. `A` checks if all items in the list are truthy, which for an empty list returns `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Same code for javascript and brainfuck (shifted 0)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 152 bytes

```javascript
+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[1.>>0]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/hfZPtfO5rW0FDPzs4gllTwPzk/rzg/J1UvJz9do0jzPwA)

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 152 bytes

```javascript
+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[+[1.>>0]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fO5rW0FDPzs4gllTw/z8A)

Comment: For which non-zero codepoint shift does it output 1?

Comment: Shift must be non-zero :/

Comment: If it's shifted zero then it's just a polyglot

Answer (score 0):

## Text, 1 byte

```
1

①

Ⅰ
```

If `one` is valid then there's no reason `①` and `Ⅰ` aren't

Comment: Add other expressions of 1 in one character here